# Below is image a simple html design

Tags: html, css

here, i want to place Notification and profile link to right side and home assignment, my course, student, message to left side. I made one div and through CSS i put it in center position and width to some %. Now, I want to place left side link and some space and right side link. how it can be done in a single div.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LFUV.jpg)

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: please share your code..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3?

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="left">
        <--!Whatever code you wrote for the home, assignment, myCourse, student, and message buttons!-->
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <--!Whatever code you wrote for the notification and profiles button!-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Does that count as one div?  I can't think of another way to do it, but I really don't know that much either so others probably know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">MyCourse</a>
 <a href="#">Student</a>
 <a href="#">Assignment</a>
 <a href="#">Message</a>
 <div class="topnav-right">
  <a href="#">Notification</a>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello :). Do you want to provide more information about your code? That would make it easier to understand what you did. Thank you!